# how to access config.paths after it is defined in main.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Here is my main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery',
        ckeditor: 'ckeditor/ckeditor',
        juiAutocomplete: 'jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom',
        tags: 'bootstrap-tokenfield',
        createPost: 'createPost',
        domReady: 'domReady',
        test: 'dropUpload'
    },
    shim: {
        createPost: {
            deps: ['domReady!']
        }
    },
    deps: ['require'],
    callback: function(require) {
        'use strice';
        var moduleName = location.pathname.replace(/\//g, '-').replace(/^-/, '');
        console.log('moduleName is: ' + moduleName);
        console.log('yes is: ' + require.config);

    }
});
```

In the callback, I'd like to access the paths which is defined in the requirejs.config() above. If it is possible, how to do it?

My purpose is to see if a module path is defined(exists). If so, then load the module script. If not checked, then a loading error will generate in the console.

Here are the available methods in requirejs by this console command. I can't find a way to access the paths I defined in requirejs.config(). Is this the right direction?

```
for (var i in requirejs) {console.log(i);}
```

config 
nextTick
version
jsExtRegExp 
isBrowser 
s 
toUrl 
undef 
defined 
specified 
onError 
createNode 
load
exec 
undef

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to get the *whole* RequireJS configuration from inside a module. You can have a `config` section in your configuration, which modules may access.

However, the problem you describe trying to solve does not require you to read the configuration. Calling `require` the normal way will load the module. If the module can't be loaded, it will generate an error on the console. Presumably you also want *your* code to know whether the loading was successful or not. You can do it with an [errback](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks):

```
require(['foo'], function (foo) {
    // Whatever you'd like to do with foo on success.
}, function (err) {
    // Whatever you'd like to do on error.
});
```

If for some reason you *must* read the config directly then it is located at `requirejs.s.contexts.<context name>.config` where `<context name>` is the name of the RequireJS context. The default context is named `_` so the configuration for it would be `requirejs.s.contexts._.config`. However, this is **not** part of the public API and can change at any time.

Comment: If the requested js file doesn't exist, the server returns a 404 page in HTML, and it is somehow interpreted by require.js, showing this error: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/js/require.js". login:8
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: I am trying this method to load js file: https://github.com/cloudchen/requirejs-bundle-examples/blob/master/src/common.js

Comment: If there is an error like this, the following script will not continue executing. That's the problem. The errback doesn't work because of this. Why require.js interpret 404 pages as script?

Comment: What you report here looks to me like a server configuration error. Some servers are configured to present a "404 page" to the user if they are requesting a URL that cannot be resolved. You must set your server to **not** present such page to the user when a `.js` file you request is non-existent.

Comment: But try this: https://www.google.com.hk/abc.js , server will always return 404 html if requested file doesn't exist. Is it so?

Comment: https://www.google.com.hk/abc.js is an example of a server serving a 404 page when resolving a URL for which there is no data. To perform a better test do this: open `www.google.com` (or the `.hk` one), find the URL of an actual script `.js` file that it loads, copy the URL, add a typo in it and then try to load it using a browser or `curl`. You won't get a 404 page. You'll get a 404 status and no contents.